# How to prevent date from getting distorted after manipulation in r

Tags: r, data-cleaning

The data was manipulated multiple times in R and exported as csv or xlsx format.

In excel the original date looks normal: `(time = c("2016-08-10 09:30:01", "2016-08-11 09:30:01", "2016-08-12 09:30:01", "2016-08-13 09:30:01", "2016-08-14 09:30:01", "2016-08-15 09:30:01")`, but after reading into R again and plotted in graphs, it got distorted and looks like `0001-01-16, 0001-01-16, 0001-02-16` on the graph.

How could I change the date and make it normal? Thank you very much.

Comment: We cannot tell what kind of error you made because you did not show either the original file that was read into R or the code that was used to do that action. Need more complete description. Read [MCVE]

Comment: @42- Thanks for your feedback. I would try to do it next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you parse this input correctly, things should work. Here we use `anytime()` from the [anytime](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=anytime) package which is robust to input types and formats:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> time <- c("2016-08-10 09:30:01", "2016-08-11 09:30:01", "2016-08-12 09:30:01", 
+            "2016-08-13 09:30:01", "2016-08-14 09:30:01", "2016-08-15 09:30:01")
R> anytime(time)
[1] "2016-08-10 09:30:01 CDT" "2016-08-11 09:30:01 CDT" "2016-08-12 09:30:01 CDT"
[4] "2016-08-13 09:30:01 CDT" "2016-08-14 09:30:01 CDT" "2016-08-15 09:30:01 CDT"
R>
```

These are now `POSIXct` objects so you can use them to plot, analyse, summarize, ...

```
R> diff(anytime(time))
Time differences in days
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
R>
```

The comment by @42 is still correct though:  your question is little lacking in specifics and detail.

Comment: Thanks Dirk, that helped. I'll try to include more details next time.